# Blocks, scoping and setting variables Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, scoping

I am using AFNetworking AFHTTPSessionManager to make a GET request. When I log the response object, the responseObject is logged. When I try to log my locationIDsDictionary, I get null. Scoping issue? Does locationIDsDictionary need to be a _block type?

```
viewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *locationIDsDictionary;

viewController.m
    [[LPAuthClient sharedClient]GET:getLocationIDString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                _locationArray = responseObject[@"data"];
                NSLog(@"Response %@", responseObject);
            });
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure %@", error);
    }];

    NSLog(@"locationIDsDictionary %@", _locationIDsDictionary);
```

EDIT: Output

```
 Response {
data =     (
            {
        id = 45388148;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "TESTING HATE VENUE";
    },
            {
        id = 208947000;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "The Greatest Isreal";
    },
            {
        id = 86128772;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "Pike street";
    },
            {
        id = 33208867;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = abcde;
    },
            {
        id = 104267842;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "somewhere over south dakota";
    },
            {
        id = 232446516;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = wow;
    },
            {
        id = 107511313;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "Yum Yum.com";
    },
            {
        id = 189736241;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "wow;l";
    },
            {
        id = 246109339;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = Fused;
    },
            {
        id = 153279132;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = 333;
    },
            {
        id = 115790356;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = "Bar Karma";
    },
            {
        id = 50341151;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = popoopo;
    },
            {
        id = 121590347;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = 26;
    },
            {
        id = 75286586;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = wow;
    },
            {
        id = 72889805;
        latitude = "37.785834";
        longitude = "-122.406417";
        name = test;
    },
            {
        id = 284599098;
        latitude = "37.785834009";
        longitude = "-122.406416997";
        name = "Urban Safari";
    },
            {
        id = 89500038;
        latitude = "37.785835266";
        longitude = "-122.406417847";
        name = "Cali Home";
    },
            {
        id = 8736810;
        latitude = "37.785835266";
        longitude = "-122.406417847";
        name = "Test%20Test%20Test";
    },
            {
        id = 45031994;
        latitude = "37.78584";
        longitude = "-122.4064";
        name = japaneses;
    },
            {
        id = 35874897;
        latitude = "37.785806574";
        longitude = "-122.406477728";
        name = "Hotel Palomar Fifth Floor Restaurant";
    }
);
meta =     {
    code = 200;
};
```

}

Comment: because you did not assign a value to it?

Comment: Please show the declaration of _locationIDsDictionary, please show the complete NSLog output which begins with the word "Response".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on CrimsonChris' answer, the `GET: parameters: success:` method is asynchronous. In this code:

```
[[LPAuthClient sharedClient] GET:getLocationIDString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _locationArray = responseObject[@"data"];
            NSLog(@"Response %@", responseObject);
        });
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure %@", error);
}];
NSLog(@"locationIDsDictionary %@", _locationIDsDictionary);
```

The `success` parameter is your completion block so:

```
^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _locationArray = responseObject[@"data"];
            NSLog(@"Response %@", responseObject);
        });
    }
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure %@", error);
}
```

is only called when iOS **completes** your download task, so your dictionary is only being allocated when the download task completes. Meanwhile, the remaining lines of code are being executed, hence the meaning of asynchronous - performed on a different thread. If it was synchronous, the code would be halted until that block of code is finished, which is bad and you see it translated into freezy UI in iOS apps.

So `NSLog(@"locationIDsDictionary %@", _locationIDsDictionary);` is still called while your download task is being performed, hence it will evaluate to `nil` - that is of course unless your internet speed is **insane** :)

Comment: so where would I set the locationIDsDictionary?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs You're allocating it in the **right** place, you're just `NSLog`ging it in the wrong place. You're `NSLog`ging before it's even initialised, so if you want to check if it's being properly initialised `NSLog` it in the completion block after you allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

You write...

> When I try to log my locationIDsDictionary, I get null.

Since you didn't share *where* this log is, I'm going to assume you are doing something like this...

```
[self runMyGetLocationMethodAsynchronously];
NSLog(@"%@", _locationIDsDictionary);
```

This won't work because you set `_locationIDsDictionary` in the *success* block of your *asynchronous* method. Your dictionary won't be set until that block runs.